# How do you type Warsaw in Romaji?

Tags: katakana, rōmaji

I'm learning Japanese and just beginning to type.

When I type `warusawa` in Romaji mode, this is what I see by default:

[image]

But what I want is this:

[image]

Is it only possible by typing in Katakana mode? Or is `sa` not the correct input for the digraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, `sa` is not the correct input. You need to type `sha` or `sya` to get シャ, meaning it's actually "Warushawa" - somewhat closer to Polish pronunciation